# symfony2 file download manager

Tags: file, symfony, authorization, download, bundle

I'm looking for a Bundle for Symfony2 which will allow specific user access to download files like .zip .pdf. Users can login and download files that they are authorized to access.As long as the user is "Authenticated" and have the correct roles.

I would also like the ability to send someone a download URL which has a specific life time, and dies once the download has been successful.

I have looked on packagist.org and the nearest I can find is chilldev/file-manager-bundle, However it does not have the access control and URL generation. I have also looked in knpbundles.com and could not find anything.

Does anyone know of a bundle which has the type of functionality? It will save me a load of development time.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no such bundle. You need to code the security stuff on your own or try to combine some existing bundles.

Worth to have a look at:

**Sonata Project** https://github.com/sonata-project

**FriendsOfSymfony** https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I have the security side covered with a FOS Bundle and a role authorization bundle.  As i found the chilldev/file-manager-bundle it thought something coming close to what I'm looking for. Looks like I have to cludge one together.

Answer (score 0):

it may be a bit late but, I recommend checking this bundle: [NzoFileDownloaderBundle](https://github.com/NAYZO/NzoFileDownloaderBundle)